# Telling FlinkSQL to read a directory of Parquet files in order

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

Is it possible to tell FlinkSQL to read the Parquet files in a directory in a particular order? i.e. I have files test-a.parquet, test-b.parquet, test-c.parquet in a folder test/. When I point FlinkSQL to read test/, is it guaranteed to read these things in order?

Also what happens in a parallel deployment? Will machine one proceed to read test-a, machine two proceed to read test-b?

Answer (score 1):

The FileSource (which is what Flink SQL uses) does not take order into account.

Comment: I was recommended to consult this file: https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-connectors/flink-connector-files/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/connector/file/src/assigners/LocalityAwareSplitAssigner.java. Do you know if this is indeed the one used for Parquet readers from S3?